# Working with DatePicker in WPF : Subtraction, Addition problem

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datepicker, timespan

Have Two DatePicker Controls and one button on my WPF page. The Click event of button shows the number of days between datePicker2 and datePicker1.

I am trying to use the following code, but code couldn't compile and gives the **System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'Subtract' and no extension method 'Subtract' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)** Error

Here's the Code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan diff1 = datePicker1.SelectedDate.Subtract(datePicker1.SelectedDate);
        i = diff1.TotalDays;
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString(), "Show");
    }
```

I tried using DisplayDate in place of SelectedDate but that code always output 0.

Comment: Sorry to bother, i got the issue sorted out.....defined two DateTime variable and did the casting like this : `DateTime d1 = DateTime(datePicker1.SelectedDate)` and then subtracted them....

**Thanks all**

Comment: Are you subtracting the same date ? its bound to be zero

Comment: No No i am dividing different dates....The reason was that DatePicker.SelectedDate is a nullable property....I got the issue sorted out by casting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DatePicker.SelectedDate` returns a Nullable, which indeed has no method `Substract`. You can simply do

```
TimeSpan diff1 = datePicker2.SelectedDate - datePicker1.SelectedDate;
```

Another option would be to cast both nullable types of `SelectedDate` to normal `DateTime`.